# Building A Docker RPM on Fedora

Tags: docker, fedora, rpmbuild, fedora-21

I am trying to build RPM from src.rpm for docker in fedora. I got the src.rpm package from here: http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=610523

I am following this guide: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch11s03.html

Now,as soon as I ran rpmbuild, I get the following error:

```
[peeyush@localhost ~]$ rpmbuild --rebuild docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.src.rpm 
Installing docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.src.rpm
error: Failed build dependencies:
    btrfs-progs-devel is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    device-mapper-devel is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    glibc-static is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    go-md2man is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket) is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(code.google.com/p/gosqlite/sqlite3) is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/Sirupsen/logrus) >= 0.6.0 is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/coreos/go-systemd/activation) >= 2-1 is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/docker/libtrust) >= 0-0.2 is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/docker/libtrust/trustgraph) >= 0-0.2 is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/godbus/dbus) is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/gorilla/mux) >= 0-0.13 is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/kr/pty) >= 0-0.19 is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/syndtr/gocapability/capability) >= 0-0.7 is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
    golang(github.com/tchap/go-patricia/patricia) is needed by docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.x86_64
```

The interesting part is, I already have golang installed:

```
[peeyush@localhost ~]$ rpm -q golang
golang-1.3.3-1.fc21.x86_64
```

Please help me figure out what is the issue here? Or could you please tell me if there is any other way to build the docker RPM.

Comment: I suspect that it says `golang`, because those are Go packages. Did you try to install those packages through `gopm`?

Comment: I couldn't find any package named gopm. Could you tell the exact package name, so I could try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if your goal is simply to install a newer version of the Docker package, consider:

```
# yum --enablerepo=updates-testing install docker-io
```

Which at the moment will get you `docker-io.x86_64 0:1.5.0-2.fc21`.

---

You need to install all the required dependencies before you are able to build the package.  You can manually inspect the source RPM using `rpm -q`:

```
$ rpm -qp --requires docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.src.rpm
btrfs-progs-devel
device-mapper-devel
glibc-static
go-md2man
golang >= 1.2.1-3
golang >= 1.3.3
golang(code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket)
golang(code.google.com/p/gosqlite/sqlite3)
golang(github.com/Sirupsen/logrus) >= 0.6.0
golang(github.com/coreos/go-systemd/activation) >= 2-1
golang(github.com/docker/libtrust) >= 0-0.2
golang(github.com/docker/libtrust/trustgraph) >= 0-0.2
golang(github.com/godbus/dbus)
golang(github.com/gorilla/mux) >= 0-0.13
golang(github.com/kr/pty) >= 0-0.19
golang(github.com/syndtr/gocapability/capability) >= 0-0.7
golang(github.com/tchap/go-patricia/patricia)
pkgconfig(systemd)
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
```

You can manually install those requirements, making sure that you meet
the version requirements, or you can automate the process using the
`yum-builddep` command, which is available in the `yum-utils` package:

```
$ sudo yum-builddep docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.src.rpm
```

Which will probably tell you:

```
[...]
Error: No Package found for golang(github.com/docker/libtrust) >= 0-0.2
Error: No Package found for golang(github.com/docker/libtrust/trustgraph) >= 0-0.2
```

This is because the package you are trying to build relies on packages
that have not yet been released.  They *are* in the `updates-testing`
repository, so you can run:

```
$ sudo yum-builddep --enablerepo=updates-testing \
  docker-io-1.5.0-1.fc21.src.rpm
```

And this will install all the requirements.